# how to compare an objects array and a nested objects array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, angular7, arrayobject

I have only been programming for a short time and I am faced with a data structure that is difficult to understand.I have a function where I get an array of objects, representing products added to a cart.

```
  getAllAddedItems(addedItems) {

    this.fullInfoAddedItems.push(addedItems);
    const filtered = this.fullInfoAddedItems.reduce((filtered, item) => {
      if ( !filtered.some(filteredItem => JSON.stringify(filteredItem) === JSON.stringify(item)) ) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
      return filtered;
    }, []);
    this.fullInfoAddedItems = filtered;
}
```

As a result I get the following array of objects

```
[
  {
    "price": 0,
    "functional_id": "carnet_de_conventions",
    "quantity": 3
  },
  {
    "price": 0,
    "functional_id": "depliants_services_incinération",
    "quantity": 4
  }
]
```

The problem is that I need a data "name" that is in an array of nested objects to complete the view information.

This would be the structure of the array

```
[

{
  "name": "Articles funeraires",
  "functional_id": "funeral",
  "generic": "incineris",
  "products": [
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Boîte de sympathie",
      "id": 27,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "1 boîte",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "boite_de_sympathie_1_boite"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Coffret empreinte rouge",
      "id": 8,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Carton de 10 coffrets",
          "price": 140,
          "functional_id": "carton_de_10_coffrets_2_recharges_argile_offertes_coloris_rouge"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "AfuBOX",
      "id": 10,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name" : "PACK N°1 comprenant :",
          "price": 30,
          "functional_id": "afubox_6_petits_modeles_4_moyens_modeles",
          "quantity": 4
        },
        {
          "name" : "PACK N°2 comprenant :",
          "price": 70,
          "functional_id": "afubox_6_petits_modeles_4_moyens_modeles",
          "quantity": 6
        }

      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Catalogue d'urnes décoratives",
      "id": 20,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "catalogue_urnes_decoratives"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sorting": 2200
},
  {
  "name": "Documents",
  "functional_id": "incineris_doc",
  "generic": "incineris",
  "products": [
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Carnet de conventions",
      "id": 17,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "carnet_de_conventions",
          "quantity": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Affiches procédure",
      "description": "De prise en charge et de crémation des animaux",
      "id": 18,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "affiches_procedure_de_prise_en_charge_et_de_cremation_des_animaux"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Dépliants services de crémation",
      "description": "Pour animaux de compagnie",
      "id": 19,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "depliants_services_incinération",
          "quantity": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Catalogue d'urnes décoratives",
      "id": 20,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "catalogue_urnes_decoratives"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sorting": 2400
},
{
  "name": "Matériel crémation",
  "functional_id": "furniture",
  "generic": "incineris",
  "products": [
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Sacs blancs",
      "description": "Pour les crémations Plurielles",
      "id": 11,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Petit modèle",
          "description": "Par 25",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "sacs_blancs_pour_les_cremations_plurielles_petit_modele_par_25"
        },
        {
          "name": "Moyen modèle",
          "description": "Par 20",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "sacs_blancs_pour_les_cremations_plurielles_moyen_modele_par_20"
        },
        {
          "name": "Grand modèle",
          "description": "Par 10",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "sacs_blancs_pour_les_cremations_plurielles_grand_modele_par_10"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Sacs bordeaux",
      "description": "Pour les crémations Référence",
      "id": 12,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Petit modèle",
          "description": "Par 25",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "sacs_bordeaux_pour_les_cremations_reference_petit_modele_par_10"
        },
        {
          "name": "Grand modèle",
          "description": "Par 10",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "sacs_bordeaux_pour_les_cremations_reference_grand_modele_par_10"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Sacs verts",
      "description": "Pour les crémations Privées",
      "id": 13,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Petit modèle",
          "description": "A l'unité",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "sacs_verts_pour_les_cremations_privees_petit_modele_unite"
        },
        {
          "name": "Moyen modèle",
          "description": "A l'unité",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "sacs_verts_pour_les_cremations_privees_moyen_modele_unite"
        },
        {
          "name": "Grand modèle",
          "description": "A l'unité",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "sacs_verts_pour_les_cremations_privees_grand_modele_unite"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Sacs bleus",
      "description": "Pour pièces anatomiques",
      "id": 14,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Standard",
          "description": "Par 25",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "sacs_bleus_pour_pieces_anatomiques_standard_par_25"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Etiquettes d'identification",
      "id": 15,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Standard",
          "description": "Par 50",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "etiquettes_identification_et_colliers_de_serrages_standard_par_50"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "file": "data:image/;base64,",
      "name": "Colliers de serrages",
      "id": 16,
      "path": "",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Standard",
          "description": "Par 50",
          "price": 0,
          "functional_id": "distributeurs_pour_sacs_housse_par_5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sorting": 2300
}
]
```

```
[
  {
    "price": 0,
    "functional_id": "carnet_de_conventions",
    "quantity": 3,
    "name": "Carnet de conventions"
  },
  {
    "price": 0,
    "functional_id": "depliants_services_incinération",
    "quantity": 4,
    "name": "Dépliants services de crémation"
  }
]
```

I attach a stacblitz link simulating what I'm trying to do to compare by "functional_id" to get "name" from the array of nested objects and push to the first array

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3wfgme

Someone to give me an effective option to get it.
Thank you in advance.

what I try to do is go through the second array to compare the "functional_id" of the original product with the "functional_id" of the product added to the first array, so I can extract the "name" in the first array and push it into the first array

```
this.market.forEach(function(item: any, i) {
      item.products.forEach(function(products: any, i) {
      products.items.forEach(function(sale: any, i) {
        let saleId = sale.functional_id;
        console.log(sale);
        console.log(saleId);

      });

      });
    });
```

This is what I'm trying to do, but I don't see how I can compare the two arrays

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @Yousaf  I just edited the question with your answer: thank you in advance

Comment: @javascript110899 expected output should be only those two object in array? Any specific logic behind that?

Comment: @gorak progress and clarification edited

Comment: @javascript110899, You have to anyhow loop through your `objects` then match the `functionalid` and fetch the `product name` then append to the `object `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the `addedItems` array and for each item in this array, iterate over the `products` array in each object inside `product` array and check if any of the item inside current `items` array has a `functional_id` equal to the `functional_id` of the current item from the `addedItems` array

```
getAllAddedItems(addedItems) {

  addedItems.forEach(item => {
     this.product.forEach(({products}) => {
        products.forEach(({name, items}) => {
           const index = items.findIndex(i => i.functional_id === item.functional_id);
           if (index > -1) item.name = name;
        })
     })
  })

  console.log(addedItems);
}
```

Here's a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hzphv7). Open the console to see the output of the function

Comment: Works perfect!  I see I was doing it the other way around and in a much more complicated way... thank you very much for your time and your help

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var j = 0; j <= nestedArray.length - 1; j++) {
  for (var k = 0; k <= nestedArray[j]['products'].length - 1; k++) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= inputArray.length - 1; i++) {
      let pos = nestedArray[j]['products'][k]['items'].map(ele => ele.functional_id).indexOf(inputArray[i]['functional_id']);
      if (pos != -1) {
        inputArray[i]['name'] = nestedArray[j]['products'][k]['name'];
      }
    }
  }
}
```